# Raised error is not caught by rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, actionmailer

We are having a production problem while sending emails using action mailer.

```
NameError
undefined local variable or method `to_ary' for #<Mail::Part:0x0000000008e0c998>
Did you mean?  to_addrs
```

Error appears totally random and behaves completely same way like https://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/02/the-craziest-fing-bug-ive-ever-seen/

What I want to do is to monkey patch the `missing_method` to make it work.
So I created some tests including

```rb
let(:part) { Mail::Part.new }

it 'returns self' do
   allow_any_instance_of(Mail::Message).to receive(:method_missing).and_raise(NameError, 'error part')
   expect([part].flatten).to eq [part]
end
```

and created monkey patch

```rb
require 'mail'

module Mail
  class Part < Message
    # monkey patched due to same behaviour like
    # https://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/02/the-craziest-fing-bug-ive-ever-seen/v
    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      begin
        super
        pp :hello
      rescue NameError => e
        return [self] if name.try(:to_sym) == :to_ary
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The intention of this test is that `Array#flatten` calls `to_ary` on it's content. `Mail::Part#method_missing` is normally not defined, but I created one to handle possible `NameError` from `Mail::Message#method_missing` and return the right value.

The problem is, that `Mail::Part#method_missing` is called, `super` is called and raises `NameError`, but rescue does not handle anything. `pp :hello` is skipped, because of the raised error.

So the test ends up with

```
NameError: error part

  0) Mail::Part call flatten with NameError returns self
     Failure/Error: expect([part].flatten).to eq [part]

     NameError:
       error part
     # ./spec/lib/core_ext/mail/part_spec.rb:13:in `flatten'
     # ./spec/lib/core_ext/mail/part_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/active_record_spec_helper.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Another problem also is, that the test ends up in infinite recursion, when I try

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  return [self]
end
```

The same with

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
   begin
      raises_name_error
   rescue NameError => e
      return [self] if name.try(:to_sym) == :to_ary
      raise e
   end
end

def raises_name_error
   raise NameError, 'error part'
end
```

but in this case, the rescue block handles the `NameError`.

Any idea for solution?

Comment: How do your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock look like? Did you try "isolating" your error to see if a gem dependency might be causing that?

Comment: We use bundler, which should to check dependecies for us.
I did not try that, I did not even have idea, that it could be caused by that

Comment: May I ask what would be wrong with monkeypatching `to_ary` instead of messing with `method_missing`?

Comment: Monkey-patching `missing_method` sounds more like treating the symptons rather than fixing its cause.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by

```
module Mail
  class Part < Message
    def to_ary
      []
    end
  end
end
```

My initial tries for solution were little overkill.